# How to create an infinite while loop?

Tags: python

I need to change the code below to make it so that the `while` loop will never stop.

What do I change?

```py
count = 0

while (count < 9):

    print ('The droid count is:', count)

    count = count + 1

print ("That's all the droids we have!")
```

Comment: `while (True):` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (8<9):
```

```
while (True):
```

Any condition that always evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0

while True:
    print ('The droid count is:', count)
    count = count + 1
```